# Concatenation of string in excel having today() function

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

In a cell in excel i want to concatenate a string that contain format as below ---

```
Brett201505LeeMay15
```

I am trying to do that by today function like -

```
= "Brett" & Today() & "Lee" & Today()
```

issue is how to specify date format as "yyyymm" and "mmmyy" in a single cell.

Write now when the cell format is general i am getting some number. I guess it is datevalue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression :

```
="Brett"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyymm")&"Lee"&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmyy")
```